# How to scale a plot in Julia using Plots.jl

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I am currently trying to zoom in on a plot which is very small.  How can I restrict the x-axis and y-axis such that I can see my plot up close?

Here is my current code, which works, but my plot is small compared to the rest of the image(which is actually correct, I just want to especially zoom in).

```
img = load("/Users/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx-xxx.png")

plot!(img)
plot!(x_coordinate_holder, y_coordinate_holder, color = :black,linewidth=0.4)
```

How can I only show specific ranges of x and y coordinates?

Comment: Use keyword arguments `xlim=(xmin, xmax)` and `ylim=(ymin, ymax)`.

Comment: See "Magic Arguments" [here](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/attributes/).

Comment: Actually, it might be `xlims` and `ylims`.

Comment: xlim=(xmin, xmax) and ylim=(ymin, ymax) worked thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I scaled it variably.  In my case, I am plotting a traverse of an agent on a map, so I want the scale to dynamically change(hence the use of min and max).

```
xMin = minimum(x_coordinate_holder)-50
xMax = maximum(x_coordinate_holder)+50
yMin = minimum(y_coordinate_holder)-50
yMax = maximum(y_coordinate_holder)+50

print("X-Coords: ", xMin, ", ", xMax, " Y-Coords: ", yMin, ", ", yMax, "\n")

plot(img, xlim=(xMin,xMax), ylim=(yMin, yMax), yflip = false)
plot!(x_coordinate_holder, y_coordinate_holder, color = :black, linewidth=0.4)
```